# Access recent contacts iOS 9

Tags: cncontact

It is possible to access to recent contacts on top of screen in app switcher ?

I looked in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) but I haven't found any method that allow to do that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: there is a Private API way!! let me know if you need it

Comment: @MedAbida Yes I need it, thanks :)

Comment: the idea is to target `/private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db` https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/
the problem is the device must be jailbroken, because as of iOS 8 every app is sandboxed

Comment: Thank you @MedAbida for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, there is no public API in the iOS SDK.